# How to do SVN setup for XCode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, ios7, xcode5

I am trying to setup SVN for my project. I have already created my project last month now I want to manage it on SVN. But I am not getting proper options for this. I am using following steps for this

1. XCode>Preference>Accounts> Add Repository
2. Source Control>Commit> Select files for initial commit>Add comment

After this I want to check mark option push to remote. But it is disable. Please guide me what I am missing here. For more details I have attached a screenshot. This option is at left bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SVN doesn't have push command.  When you commit changes, they are immediately sent to a repository.  That's why there is only 1 step for SVN - commit.  That's a difference with Git, where you have 2 steps - commit to local repository, push to remote repository.

Comment: Can you share more details how I can do this because when I do only this then it is not showing my files on SVN.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not showing my files on SVN"? I've created a new repo, checked it out, added project files and committed them. At this point the last commit isn't shown in Xcode Source Control > History… until I perform Source Control > Update.

Comment: I have tried to update these files but these files are not reflecting on SVN repository.

Comment: Is commit displayed when you execute in command line `svn log --limit 5 http://path/to/remote/repo`?